# jboss installation

Tags: jboss, redhat

I want to install `jboss 7` on my Redhat linux server but I am not able to do so. I have already installed JDK 1.8 and 1.7 files but i need to install `jboss 7`. Currently `jboss 5` is installed. Please help me to update the instance.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not able to do it". That is hardly a description of the problem you are having. We don't have a crystal ball to see what the problem is you are having.

Comment: thanks for your kind support

Answer (score 0):

Installation Guide for use with Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.0:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/installation_guide/